# Does the following reasoning make sense?

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

Is the following reasoning that any finite dimensional vector space can be decomposed as a direct sum valid?

1. Since finite dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic if their dimensions match and they are defined over the same field, which I will restrict to $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, there is only one one-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ up to isomorphism.
2. $\dim V=\dim U_1+\dim U_2$ if $V=U_1\oplus U_2$, therefore I can construct a vector space of any finite dimension by taking arbitrary direct sums of the unique 1-dimensional vector space over the same field.
3. Given now *any* finite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, it will always be isomorphic as a vector space to one of the vector spaces I can construct as in step 2.
4. Therefore any finite dimensional vector space can be written as a direct sum of any combination of lower dimensional vector spaces provided the dimensions add up correctly.

Comment: Your reasoning seems to show that any space is isomorphic to a direct sum, not necessarily decomposable into a direct sum itself. You can decompose the space directly by using a reasoning similar to the complete proof of part 1.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how those aren't equivalent statements. If $V$ is isomorphic to a vector space $W=U_1\oplus...\oplus U_n$ that is a direct sum of lower dimensional vector spaces, doesn't that mean $V$ can be decomposed into those lower dimensional vector spaces itself since $V\cong W$?

Comment: The problem is that $U_1,\dots,U_n$ are subsets of $W$ but probably not subsets of $V$; therefore $V$ can't possibly be an internal direct sum of the $U_j$. Can you find subsets of $V$ that play the role that the $U_j$ play for $W$?